# Overlay on image on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now when I click an image, it sets the entire page to have 60% transparency.
I'd just like this to effect the image that is clicked itself.

I am using Bootstrap so the images may vary a little in height/width.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/txrt6zo1/

```js
$(".thumb-overlay-content").on('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('rotateOut rotateIn');
});
```

```css
.thumb-overlay-content { margin:10px; background:#CCC; float:left; text-align:center; padding:0px; }
.rotateOut { border:3px solid blue; }
.rotateIn { border:3px solid green; background:green; }
.rotateIn .after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
.rotateIn .after {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>

<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `position: relative` in `.thumb-overlay-content` CSS. This will make the position of the absolve `.after` div relative to its container.

```js
$(".thumb-overlay-content").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('rotateOut rotateIn');
});
```

```css
.thumb-overlay-content {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #CCC;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.rotateOut {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.rotateIn {
  border: 3px solid green;
  background: green;
}

.rotateIn .after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.rotateIn .after {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>

<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks again @void - you're VERY good. This is much clearer now. Thank you.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk glad again!

Comment: Now I just need to work on a version that only lets me select one instead of both images ;-D

Comment: add class `rotateOut` and removeClass `rotateIn` from all the elems and then call `toggleCass`... Mark it correct it solves the thing ;)